# Can I adapt to learning Artificial intelligence in MS easily

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, artificial-intelligence

I am applying for my Masters in CS in US universities. I am very much interested in Artificial Intelligence, but some of my friends said that it would be very difficult for me to learn AI as I have no overview about the course in my undergraduate degree.

Can anyone tell me if I can easily learn by putting some effort on learning AI. I am very much interested in that course.

Comment: If you've never had a course in <XXXX>, how do you know that you're actually interested in <XXXX>?

Comment: I might have not studied AI in my UG but I have surely watched video courses on udacity.com where Google employees teach about AI. I got interested in AI. I am a computer science student in UG so I thought I would go with AI specialization in my graduation.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear.  If you've never actually **done** <XXXX>, how do you know you're interested in or good at **doing** <XXXX>?  Watching videos doesn't count as "doing".

Comment: well, yes you can adapt - but will you "like" to adapt? this is the question! - that is, take "real courses" then see if you like it or not.

Comment: @JeffE: sorry, I don't understand the meaning of your comments: do you want to say that the OP should apply for a AI course during his masters in order to find out how much interest he actually has?  Or are you questioning whether anyone can know his interest (as opposed to: abilities and possible abilities) before a course? - that is IMHO nonsense: you'll find out your abilities and limitations because interest leads you to explore them. And a course is IMHO one way to find out whether *can* get good in this particular field.

Comment: @cbeleites I'm suggesting that applying for a research degree in any topic, when you have not actually done any work in that topic, is risky.  I don't doubt his interest in the topic; I question his interest in **doing research** on that topic, when he hasn't even done **homework** on that topic yet.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the US, but in some schools in Canada you can be admitted to a CS Graduate degree without prior background in an interest area. You'd have to take background courses to get yourself up to speed, possibly in excess of the bare-minimum program requirements, but it should be doable.

For AI specifically, ensure that the schools you're applying to have enough background in the topic, and that there are supervisors and supervisory capacity for you. Look for undergraduate courses in topics that interest you, as they may form part of your background studies.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, many graduate courses do not require prior knowledge about the specific subject being taught, only background knowledge. Alternatively, they may require only minimal knowledge that you could teach yourself very quickly. But it is worth checking specific courses - naturally some would be more advanced.

For something like machine learning, the relevant background would probably be algorithms, probability, linear algebra and maybe some calculus/optimization.